# Efficiently sending 3d array of ints to client

Tags: javascript, python, image-compression

I have a Python web application and I'd like to send a 3D array of integers to the client in an efficient way. These arrays will be fairly large, around 500x500x20 or so. The integers are all between -2000 and 2000, so can fit into a signed 12 bits. They originally represent a 3D image, so can almost certainly be compressed.

I'd like to know the most efficient way to access these raw values in my JavaScript client. I'm mostly concerned about bandwidth. Is there a way to compress these losslessly as a movie or 3D image and reconstruct the original array on the client?

Comment: So you're talking about a dozen MB with lots of zeroes? have you tried simply compressing the HTTP response? lossless image compression *might* work better, but try it first and compare the sizes before you start coding on flawed assumptions. If you find that it is worth the extra code, yes, it it possible to read integers from an image.